# A public action method 'Summary' was not found on controller 'myControllerName'

Tags: mvc, upgrade

I just upgraded a test instance of my sitecore server to 8.2 (original release) from 8.1 (original release). I've followed all of the steps in the upgrade document, and now as I'm doing some manual testing, I've hit this error. I have a not-upgraded test environment that is working fine.

The `Summary` method that the .NET code is looking for is a partial HTML file that exists in the correct place in my file structure (I didn't change it when I upgraded), but now it's not finding the file. I did add a non-partial version of the file (using Summary.cshtml instead of _Summary.cshtml), however, that didn't get me anything.

How do I go about figuring out how to fix this issue?

Comment: Have you compared the dlls to see if they have the version you upgraded to?

Comment: Yes, the versions match. I even have a working copy on my local dev server, and the files seem to match as well.

Comment: is this a custom controller you built? or something within Sitecore's dlls? if so which dll and which controller and action are those?

Comment: I hope your controller/Area is registered in MVC routing & believing there is no change in MVC routing from your upgrade steps :) Did you check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745182/intermittent-asp-net-mvc-exception-a-public-action-method-abc-could-not-be-fou

Comment: Please edit your question and include the exact error / stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

So after much research, and pouring over my code, I realized that I had a compilation error that happened when I had merged my branch from the `master` branch in our source code repository. What that translated to was that my CSHTML files were expecting some code that didn't exist in my compiled DLL.

The problem didn't show up in my sandbox because I didn't have the most recent database changes in my local sandbox, but my test environment did.

So the answer was to simply **compile all of my code** and **make sure that I have the most recent copy of the Master database in my sandbox.**

I hope that other people will be able to learn from this!